# Argument types do not match parameters Error in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: typescript, next.js, prisma

When i start transfer prisma seed process file from Nest server part of my app to NextJS part - i got that [warning](https://prnt.sc/3pWUH6inbQqW)

How can i fix it? In Nest part of app there is [no such problem](https://prnt.sc/Bj59MOItrK4u) - so, it is not because of IDE settings...

Comment: Does the error go away if you pass empty paranthesis in deleteMany invocation?
So essentially can you try this: `await prisma.offerCategory.deleteMany({})`

Comment: No, [it](https://prnt.sc/p4-bN_DxdIkn) didn't help

Comment: [I can suppress](https://prnt.sc/ZPkI05iFD7dm) it for this file..
But - if i will - how can i turn it on again?

Comment: Can you check if you get the same behaviour in VS Code as well?